# Return word in a string

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar2

How can I return the second word in a varchar2 data type and blank if there is nothing? The idea is to use a function within a function.

Comment: A regular expression is probably what you need. Use it in the regexp_substr function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`substr(column, instr(column, ' ') + 1)`

edit (for second word only):

`substr(col, instr(col, ' '), instr(col, ' ', instr(col, ' ') + 1) - instr(col, ' '))`

edit again:

as pointed out by Colin, `REGEXP_SUBSTR(col,'\S+',1,2)` might be a better way of doing this

Comment: was just about to post this... here's the sqlfiddle of it:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07093/2

Comment: And how does this return just the second word and not also subsequent words?

Comment: It doesn't. I just tested it

Comment: So `select substr('one two three', instr('one two three', ' ') + 1) from dual` returns just "two"? I would expect "two three".

Comment: Beware the difference between `\w` and `\S`. In this case you probably want the latter.

Answer (score 4):

```
regexp_substr(column, '\S+', 1, 2)
```

Comment: I think I'd prefer this solution!